# How can I filter only "stories" from followed persons?

Tags: twitter

I am following several persons on Twitter, so my screen (sorry I don't know the Twitter nomenclature) is cluttered by things those people say, which discourages using Twitter at all.

Today I received an e-mail from Twitter titled "Here is what's happening on Twitter". And below in this mail were two headings: Stories and Tweets. Both sections contained Tweets ***only from people I am following***, but, the Stories section had ***the important Tweets***, exactly what I would be interested in reading on Twitter. There were only a few of them. The Tweets section contained a lot of unimportant everyday Tweets, which I am not interested in.

This mail was useful because it made possible to just read the Stories from people I am following.

Question: is there a way ***inside Twitter*** to make a filter only for "Stories" from followed people?

Comment: Twitter has gone through a number of redesigns since this question was originally asked. Is it still relevant?

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to search for tweets from people I follow which are important or popular. A good measurement for importance and popularity is how many times a tweet has been retweeted (Twitter's algorithm for "top stories" is also based or number of retweets). So let's say I am interested in displaying a list of tweets from people I follow which have been retweeted at least 2 times. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Twitter blog post](http://blog.twitter.com/2012/05/best-of-twitter-in-your-inbox.html) on the emails:

> Stories feature a design similar to the recently updated Discover tab,
>   emphasizing who shared each story beneath summaries to help you decide
>   which ones matter most to you.

So maybe the [Discover](https://twitter.com/i/discover) tab has something like what you are after.

Comment: The Discover tab is indeed showing the kind of information that looks like "Stories" (similar to what I received in the email I described). But it displays the "Stories" from everybody. When I compare "Stories" from Discover tab with "Stories" from my email, there are quite different items and actually, in the Discover "Stories" only 2 stories are from a person whom I follow, others are from strangers.

Answer (score 0):

To [view only tweets in you timeline that contain links](http://kottke.org/12/07/turn-your-twitter-stream-into-your-friends-linkblog), use this link - https://twitter.com/search/timeline/http

You can also try this - https://twitter.com/#!/search/timeline/filter%3Alinks